# How to get any changes happened in the current SDE version?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, enterprise-geodatabase

How to get any change done on the map in the current version of **sde**. using `arcObjects`
e.g. if i had a line on the map. and in the current **sde** version i changed the length of that line. how to get this particular line.

Comment: Did you try [IVersionedTable.Differences](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000m20000000)?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall yes thanks. please put it as an answer to this question. so i can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding differences between two versions. see the following link.
[Finding differences between versions](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Finding_differences_between_versions/00010000021t000000/)